# Reclaiming disk space after dropping a database?

Tags: mysql

My /var/db/mysql is 72Gb

I dropped a old backup 5Gb database expecting to free up some disk space, no change?

/var/db/mysql remains 72Gb.

How should I proceed in reclaiming my much needed (small SSD) storage space?

Google suggest I should spend days exporting the other 67Gb of data and then reimport...... this is not an option because I simply do not have anymore free space.

Thanks